# Group by category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have groups of Items. Every group has main Item or header let's say this group has items inside it.

I want to select these items inside this group and make some math on them let's say I want to sum them.

For example: the table like this

```
Code          Description        Price
-----------   -------------      -----
12-5000       Toys
12-5000-100   FIFA Game          200$
12-5000-200   PEPSI MAN          150$
12-5000-300   X-MEN              120$
12-6000       Movies
12-6000-100   Scarface           200$
12-6000-200   BADBOYS1           200$
12-6000-300   GODFAther1         120$
```

The result that I am dying to get:

```
Description   Total
-----------   -----
Toys          470
Movies        520
```

Comment: Do you really have categories and products in the same table?

Comment: What does it mean when price is blank? Is it actually 0 in your table, NULL, something else?

Comment: it's blank because I imported from Excel Sheet so it's Not null, I can check it by using LEN() function

Comment: So price is a string? Aye aye.

Answer (score 6):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT Code, Description FROM dbo.Table 
   WHERE price IS NULL -- =0? can't tell what blank means
)
SELECT x.Description, SUM(t.Price)
 FROM dbo.Table AS t
 INNER JOIN x 
 ON LEFT(t.Code, 7) = x.Code
 AND t.Code > x.Code
 GROUP BY x.Description;
```

**EDIT**

Since we've learned that price is literally stored as a string like `'400$'`...

```
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT Code, Description FROM dbo.Table 
   WHERE LEN(price) = 0
)
SELECT x.Description, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), REPLACE(t.Price,'$','')))
 FROM dbo.Table AS t
 INNER JOIN x 
 ON LEFT(t.Code, 7) = x.Code
 AND t.Code > x.Code
 GROUP BY x.Description;
```

Comment: i tried your code here it wouldn't give me anything, you know this is a little bit dump but code and description and price in the same table is not professional. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user1400575 what do you mean "wouldn't give you anything"?

Comment: if I run the inner select it brings me nothing, if I add not or <>, it brings me data but the sum is fixed '4084' appreciate your help Aaron

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you. You need to have proper data and tell us what it is. Can you explain how to identify rows that don't have a price?

Comment: shoot, I can't do this, some of 'em does not have price
But you know you can assume that all of them have a price

Comment: You came here for help, right? Do you want help, or not? I have no idea what "all of them have a price" means. How do you identify which rows are a category and which rows aren't? And don't say by looking at them. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Aaron's query runs fine with the data you supplied - Not sure what your question is-  Your data is different than supplied - change the `WHERE` appropriately.I had to add a `WHERE` to T to handle the '' convert.                                                    ;WITH x AS 
;WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT Code, Description FROM SO_TABLE26
   --WHERE LEN(price) = 0
   --WHERE Price = ''
   WHERE LEN(Code) = 7   
)
SELECT x.Description, 
SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), REPLACE(t.Price,'$','')))
 FROM SO_TABLE26 AS t 
 INNER JOIN x 
 ON LEFT(t.Code, 7) = x.Code
 WHERE T.Price <> ''
 GROUP BY x.Description;

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand sorry man for this it's complicated to explain. This is all because of my BOSS he wants it urgently (as usual) so take it easy.There is nothing to be mad of. Thanks anyway your efforts are appreciated. Musab Ghannaj

Comment: @user1400575 I'm not mad, I just don't know how to help you if all you do is throw your hands in the air and say it doesn't work, but aren't specific enough for me to help you fix it.

Comment: Wow.  Give better info for better answers.  If the inner query returns nothing change the where clause based off of your actual data, since you didn't supply good data for us to help you with.  Run a select and copy the value on your clipboard, say WHERE <> and paste.  Or try  --WHERE LEN(price) = 0
   --WHERE Price = ''
   --WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Price)) = ''
   --WHERE LEN(Code) = 7   Also, you may need to add WHERE T.Price <> '' BEFORE GROUP BY x.Description  Can you run it now?

Answer (score 0):

```
select description, sum(price)
from tableName
group by description
```

Can't be that easy?

***EDIT***

I see. You have headers (th) & rows (tr) in the same table. Then you need to isolate them into two pseudo tables. Maybe this:

```
select th.description, SUM(tr.price)
from tableName th
left join tableName tr
on tr.code like th.code + '-%'
where th.code like '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
group by th.description
```

Comment: No, because this would show separate rows for `FIFA Game`, `Pepsi Man` etc. The grouping isn't meant to be on the description column.

Comment: Couldn't understand it a little

Comment: th is a filtered list of the "header" records. I do the filtering by matching a pattern of 2 digits, a dash, then 4 digits. In Aaron's (better) solution, he's doing this same thing using LEN(price) = 0. Once you have the th records, I was joining to the table again, as tr (detail row) records. The join is on the same header code, with a dash, and then something else (% wildcard). Sum the values on the rows, and group by the header description.